# How to resize a wx.SimpleHtmlListBox to its "optimum" dimensions?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using a wx.SimpleHtmlListBox() to display some HTML items in a popup window on my wxPython app. Now I must resize the list box so that all elements are visible and no scroll bars are shown. So my question is: how to resize the listbox to it's "optimum" size?

Actually, I managed to get the optimum height of the listbox by using `lb.GetLinesHeight(0, lb.Count)`, but what about the width?

Notice that since each listbox elements may contain HTML, they may greatly vary in width, so you cannot use tricks like `width = (lb.CharWidth * char_width_of_longest_element)`.